# Views in Django: Sending array with dictionaries

Tags: python, django, dictionary, templates, view

I am looking for a smart solution on how to provide data to my template in django. Given is a array, filled with dictionaries.

```
    in the file "views" i have:
from .pymodules import url_scraper as spider
from .pymodules import url_list


def result(request):
    top10 = spider(url_list) #array filled with dicts
    return render(request, "result.html", {"top10" : top10}

## example for top10 --> [{"key1" : "value_A"},{"key1" : "value_B"},{"key1" : "value_C"}]
```

Now i have the problem, that everything I try does not give me the "key" : "value" output i want.

Trying for something like this:

```
{% x in top10 %}
  {x[key]} ## key is given
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django templates using `obj.attr` will do a dictionary lookup (`obj[attr]`), then an attribute lookup (`obj.attr`) and then a method call with no arguments (`obj.attr()`)

```
{% for x in top10 %}
  {{ x.key }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you would like to use some standard python syntax in your template you can [use Jinja2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2)

Answer (score 0):

1. if you do not know the key name.

   - use for loop

   ```
   # template
   {% for val in top10 %}
       {% for k, v in val.items %}
           {{ k }} is key.
           {{ v }} is value.
       {% endfor %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   - use custom template filter

   ```
   from django.template import Library

   register = Library()

   @register.filter(name='demo')
   def demo(value):
       for k, v in value:
           return '%s--%s' % (k, v)
   ```

   ```
   {% for val in top10 %}
       {{ val|demo }}
   {% endfor %}
   ```
2. if you know the key name.

   ```py
   {% for x in top10 %}
       {{ x.keyname }}
   {% endfor %}
   ```